# rust compiler "error: no matching package named `*` found" though it should be present

Tags: rust

A while back I setup a project with the following in my `Cargo.tml`:

```
[dependencies]
reqwest = { version = "0.11", features = ["blocking", "json"] }
```

That all worked great. Now I tried to add an additional dependency by adding the line `teloxide = { version = "0.4", features = ["auto-send", "macros"] }` to `Cargo.tml` and get an error of:

`error: no matching package named 'teloxide' found`

I'm not sure what is the cause of this error, or what to investigate further - perhaps there is some way I can see which packages the compiler can list/recognize? I've found these two threads but they don't seem to provide any conclusive answer (I did try removed `~/.cargo` which resulted in no change in behavior):

https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/6686
https://github.com/balena-os/balena-raspberrypi/issues/261

Potentially the issue is related to nix or naersk which I'm using.

Comment: How are you adding "teloxide" in your `Cargo.toml`?

Comment: I've updated the question with that.

Comment: I've added both lines to a blank project and it works fine. Can you gives us more details about your setup/project? Maybe you made a configuration change somewhere and forgot about it?

Comment: If you're using visual studio code, I'm using https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=serayuzgur.crates to help me manage crates.io dependencies. It gives a tick beside a dependency if everything is fine after parsing the line and pinging the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with a simple `cargo update`.

Answer (score 2):

I landed on this page.  I am sharing my shame, to save you time:

Failed:

`async_process = "1.2.0"`

Worked:

`async-process = "1.2.0"`

Comment: encounter same :P

that's the catch