# No matching package found

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, yew

I am trying to integrate an API in a yew project and facing the following issue:

```
Dark@Dark:/var/www/html/yew-practice$ wasm-pack build --target web
Error: Error during execution of `cargo metadata`:     Updating crates.io index
    Updating git repository `https://github.com/yewstack/yew`
error: no matching package found
searched package name: `yewtil`
perhaps you meant:      yew
location searched: https://github.com/yewstack/yew
```

Cargo.toml:

```
[package]
name = "yew-practice"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2018"

[lib]
crate-type = ["cdylib"]

[dependencies]
wasm-bindgen = "^0.2"
serde="1"
yew = { git = "https://github.com/yewstack/yew" }
yewtil = { git = "https://github.com/yewstack/yew", features = ["fetch"] }
```

How do I solve the problem above?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [rust compiler "error: no matching package named \`\*\` found" though it should be present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68150689/rust-compiler-error-no-matching-package-named-found-though-it-should-be-p)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error tells you that no package `yewtil` was found in the Git repository. If you go to the repository and check its `Cargo.toml` file, you will indeed notice that it doesn't include a `yewtil` package.

I searched in the repository for `yewtil`, and found this pull request that refactored the project and merged `yewtil` into other packages: [yewstack/yew#1842](https://github.com/yewstack/yew/pull/1842/commits/daa11bd766af75a5e242c860cd58adfd9153fa52).

You have two options now:

1. Drop the dependency on `yewtil`, and use the [documentation](https://docs.rs/yew/0.18.0/yew/) to figure out where the features have moved that you want to use.
2. Add a `tag` key to the dependency to pull in the latest release that included `yewtil`, or simply switch to the latest published version on crates.io.

If you want to get the latest features from `yew`, which appears to be the case given that you're pulling in the package from GitHub and not crates.io, go with option 1. You can use the documentation and the examples in the `master` branch to see how to use the package in its latest version.

Answer (score 0):

`Yew` git repository is not a valid address, it must end with `.git`.

```
git = "https://github.com/yewstack/yew.git"
```

Comment: That's actually not true. Check the examples in Cargo's documentation, none of them ends with `.git`: https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/specifying-dependencies.html#specifying-dependencies-from-git-repositories